# Continuous functions on a closed subset of a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space with $Y$ a closed subspace with relative topology.  If $f:Y \rightarrow Z$ is a continuous map of topological spaces, then can $f$ always be extended to be from $X$ to $Z$?  If not, if possible, please provide a counterexample where $X, Y, Z$ are all metric spaces. (Euclidean space if possible)

I was looking into examples with $X$ being the cantor set.  But my intuition for such pathological things is not great.  I also tried examples where $X$ is a finite set with funny topologies, but got nowhere.

Comment: Can be extended! Maybe not continuously! Look up the Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: I am only interested in continuous extensions.  Any function can be trivially extended to a superset using the axiom of choice.  Thank you for the reminder of the Tietze extension theorem.  I forgot about that one.  In particular, compact or even Lindelof metric spaces are normal, and as are Euclidean spaces.

Comment: I am assuming that since a named theorem corresponds to a rather special case (The assumptions on $X$ are not that much, but the assumptions on $Z$ are very much) that the problem, as I posed it, would be both difficult and uninteresting except perhaps in select special cases outside of reach of Tietze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity map $S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ cannot be extended to a continuous map $B^{n}\to S^{n-1}$ (see [Brouwer's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem)). The simplest instance of this is the case $n=1$, when $S^{0}=\{-1,1\}$ and $B^1=[-1,1]$; then the conclusion follows from the intermediate value theorem.

A space $Z$ is an *[absolute retract](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Retract_of_a_topological_space)* if the extension property in your question holds for all $(X,Y)$ pairs.   I'm not sure  this notion is really used for general $ Y$; usually one assumes $Y$ normal (thus defining the absolute retract property  in the class of normal spaces) or  a metric space. This property is often abbreviated AR.  It comes up in *General Topology* by Willard; there are also two books titled *Theory of Retracts*, one of them by Borsuk.

E.g., vector spaces are absolute retracts. The AR property forces the topology of $Z$ to be more or less trivial (namely, all homotopy groups are trivial). But a related property ANR (absolute neighborhood retract) is satisfied by many interesting spaces. E.g., the survey *[Absolute Neighborhood Retracts and Shape Theory](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mardesic.pdf)* by Sibe Mardesic.